# Fuzzy Match using SQL Server Standard Edition 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates, fuzzy-logic

I have a question about de-duplicating/cleansing a list of companies and addresses (90K) and merging them. An example of this list would be

```
Google, Google INC, G INC, Google - New York, Google Chicago
```

with a different or same address. All in all, the data is a mess.

My constraints are that to do this, I only have access to SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard. Therefore I don't have Master Data Services. I've read many blog posts using SOUNDEX, Levenshtein etc. but don't believe they would be effective enough. Also, I have considered CLR Functions but have read they take a long time.

My question is, given the type of data that I have with the constraints, what method (algorithm, CLR function, something else) would the best results? Recommendations for solutions outside of SQL Server would also be appreciated as well.

Please let me know if you would like any other additional information to come to a conclusion.

Comment: The best way to cleanse addresses is to use address normalization software. There are very expensive CASS certified programs, and far less expensive programs that should work for your purposes. I have used address normalization libraries in the past that can be called from C#. Read data out, normalize through the library, write corrected address back to the database. SOUNDEX will not work. Not sure about normalizing the company name. Seems you would want to keep the original name but perhaps add a column that is a cleaned version. Perhaps write code that removes common suffixes and city names?

Comment: Since it is a one-time job, you could try to: 1) split all names into separate rows `<same_id, name_part_1>; <same_id, name_part_2>` 2) filter out all prefixes/suffixes a @EricJ. said 3) try `soundex` and `like`. Push all the split values into staging table and go on with trimming/replacing/transliterating and so on.

Comment: Soundex is really inappropriate for combining similar company names. It will falsely combine companies that happen to have the same Soundex key. It's like the hash collision problem on steroids.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. Is there an algorithm that anyone knows of that would be best to use in matching company names? e.g Bank of America, Bank Of America Acquisition Group, Bank of America Business Capital, Bank of Amerika